# Kotlin Compose Multiplatform Desktop JVM Fatal Error

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm looking to learn and test Compose Multiplatform. I've cloned https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform-template and Gradle builds OK. When running the build though, the JVM hits a fatal error:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe54bffde60, pid=4397, tid=4429
Problematic frame:
C  [libstdc++.so.6+0x229e60]

I'm trying to run this on WSL2 and I've tried multiple Java 17 JDK distributions. Is there any known compatibility issue with WSL2?

Comment: It works under the same Ubuntu (23.04) and multiple JVMs (17.0.9-ms, 17.0.8-oracle, 17.0.8.1-tem) when running in VMPlayer. When running the desktopApp in WSLg though, the JVMs all fail in libstdc++.so.6 just with different offsets.